# Python: unicode .encode, can a function be called on unencodable characters?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I have a text, in uncode, that I'd like to encode in latin-1. Some characters cannot be encoded. If I use encode with the "replace" parameter, I get the question tag character, but, is there a way to call a custom function to replace the character?

For example, I'd like to convert all the possible characters to latin-1, and call `unidecode.unidecode()` on the unencodable characters. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own error handler with [`codecs.register_error('myerrorhandler', function)`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.register_error).

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.register_error('silly', lambda e: ('X', e.start+1))
>>> 'foöbar'.encode('ascii', 'silly')
b'foXbar'
>>>
```

Comment: I'm having problems making your code work... `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Are you using Python 2? If so you would need to use `u'foöbar'` and `u'X'` for this code to work.